# Role of shape parameter in spaces.Box()

Tags: python-3.x, reinforcement-learning, openai-gym

I am making a custom gym environment for RL but I don't understand the function Box. I understood the low and high parameters but I didn't understand the shape argument.

Can someone explain the shape argument in Box?

For example I want a continuous space between -1 and 1:

```
a = spaces.Box(low=-1, high=1, shape=(1, ))
```

What is the role of shape here? I just want my space to be between -1 and +1

Comment: Any breakthrough?